# .each() jquery function inside AJAX Success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have flip-cards with a word, and a translation of that word on the back. I have built an .each() function to find what side of the flip-card has the tallest content, and make that side have a relative position, so that the card container is always as big as the tallest content.

I have successfully implemented the .each() function when my page loads. It is as follows:

```
$('.word-card').each(function(){


    var frontHeight = $(this).find(".front").outerHeight();
    var backHeight = $(this).find(".back").outerHeight();

    if(frontHeight > backHeight){
        $(this).find('.front').css( { position: 'relative', 'min-height': '150px'  });
        $(this).find('.back').css( { position: 'absolute', top: '0', left: '0' });
    } else {
        $(this).find('.back').css( { position: 'relative', 'min-height': '150px'  });
        $(this).find('.front').css( { position: 'absolute', top: '0', left: '0' });
    }
});
```

My site however, appends new divs via an AJAX call. So I tried to shift the function into the success section of my AJAX call, as follows:

```
success: function(response){

        var $response = $(response);


        $($response).find('.word-card').each(function(){
            var frontHeight = $(this).find(".front").outerHeight();
            var backHeight = $(this).find(".back").outerHeight();
            if(frontHeight > backHeight){
                $(this).find('.front').css( { position: 'relative', 'min-height': '150px'  });
                $(this).find('.back').css( { position: 'absolute', top: '0', left: '0' });
            } else {
                $(this).find('.back').css( { position: 'relative', 'min-height': '150px'  });
                $(this).find('.front').css( { position: 'absolute', top: '0', left: '0' });
            }
        })


        $container.isotope().append($response).isotope('appended', $response);

    },
```

But this does not work as expected. The styles are applied as if the frontHeight and backHeight variables are returning 'false'.

I have tried many many different attempts at fixing this. So many, that retelling what I have done would be a waste of everyones time.

Essentially, via the browser debugger, I believe the 'this' in the success function is not targeting the correct element.

I cannot, however, resolve the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: try `$response.find` instead of `$($response).find`. $response is already a jQuery object, you don't need to wrap it in another jQuery object. Pretty sure that will lead to problems.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that in my travels, but quickly checked again, still getting the wrong element targeted. I get this in the debugger:
`  success: function(response){
    var $response = $(response);

    $response.find('.word-card').each(function(){

       var frontHeight = $(this).find(".front").outerHeight();
    var backHeight = $(this).find(".back").outerHeight();`

Comment: sorry what do you mean "i get this in the debugger". You mean it writes that string to the console? If so, why? There's nothing in the code that explicitly does that. Anyway all that's doing is reproducing some of your code, I'm not sure why that would be useful. A better question is: are you sure that "response" contains HTML in the correct structure? maybe post a sample of what "response" looks like into the question

Comment: Yeah, had trouble with the miniMarkdown. Not sure how to put code in in these answer sections.It doesn't write to console, but in the source tab of the debugger. I am stepping through the function and it basically stops at:
`$response.find('.word-card').each(function()`

var frontHeight returns nothing, making the rest of the function fail.

Comment: don't put your HTML code in the comments section, edit the question and include it there. Large portions are code in comments are unreadable anyway.